# Constraint Layout Changing Through The Screen Size

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I am working on a project and I can't figure it out after long time searching, how to manage and fit my layout to every screen size.
I tried everything and it just split the objects on the screen.
I need to create a stable layout that doesn't change through the different screen sizes.
I will appreciate your help.

Comment: The question is too generic. You can start from this and read further:
https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Answer (score 1):

If you want a layout that shows correctly across various screen sizes, try not to hard code positions of the objects inside the layout. For example, don't use `android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"` and|or `android:paddingLeft="50dp"`, etc to position the object inside the layout.

Instead, use more of
 `android:layout_weight` and `android:layout_gravity` in LinearLayout

and
 `android:layout_centerInParent`, `android:layout_centerHorizontal` or `android:layout_centerVertical` in RelativeLayout.

Make sure the parent layout has:

```
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
```

Answer (score 0):

In Constraint layout,you can use the **Chaining feature** [ConstraintLayout Chains](https://medium.com/@nomanr/constraintlayout-chains-4f3b58ea15bb) to spread views across the screen. In addition to that you have the option to specify 0 width and height, and manage the width and height with the **constraint ratio** feature [Constraint layout ratio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41265570/constraintlayout-aspect-ratio) so that your User Interface becomes dynamic with respect to screen size. You can refer the full documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/) and [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout).