# Android ImageView not show perfect

Tags: android, imageview, picasso

I am using Picasso to show images from url. My issue is , when I used debug APK, all images in list and grid view show perfect, whenever I upload APK to play store and install Live app, some of image stretch height wise. I did not give width and height in layout. I am not able to figure out the issue. Please help.

Debug App[image: Debug app screenshot]

Live app[image: Live app screenshot]

Screenshot from both app is added.

Comment: Please clarify your question then we get idea please add code or photos

Comment: @SarthakDhami - Screenshot added.

Comment: I have added one library please add and try i hope this library works fine and please give your valuable review to my post

Comment: you can fix the height in layout and resize your image in picasso

Comment: @kelvin if I do so as you said, image quality may me lose and image not look perfect.

Comment: who uploads the images? You can always provide cropping function when uploading image

Comment: @kelvin - Images upload by back-end developer, they added images in 3 format 1-square 2-rectangle with less height and 3- rectangle image with high height.

Answer (score 1):

**Try this Glide This is perfect for Url Image.**

```
 Add this library to your gradle file
 implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.11.0'

 Glide.with(OurAppsActivity.this)
 .load(image_url)
 .into(your_ImageView);
```

Comment: I check both Picasso and Glide lib but not working.

Comment: then you have to add Code otherwise in my Project Glide working fine

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps what you need is making images have fixed aspect ratio on all phones.

1. Customize ImageView: https://github.com/santalu/aspect-ratio-imageview/
2. Use ConstraintLayout: [ConstraintLayout aspect ratio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41265570/constraintlayout-aspect-ratio)