# How to design responsive images for ViewPager2

Tags: android, android-viewpager, picasso

I use `ViewPager2` in android application. The width of it is `match_parent` and the height is 300 dp.  I use Picasso library to load images from URL to `ViewPager2`. There is one problem is when I use a tablet, the image's width must match to parent but height is fixed and it makes images ugly.

What is the best way to show images but on different devices?

```
Picasso.get()
    .load(slideritem1.getimage())
    .fit()
    .into(imageView);
```

Comment: In constraint layout and use `app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio` this property here is example https://stackoverflow.com/a/46159914/9868485

Comment: create layout for tablet variation. so new layout will create for tablet now do changes as per your requirements.

Comment: thx both comments helped me to design app better